# NEO4J - Regular expression with Python

Tags: python, neo4j

I have an expression like this who work fine in Neo4J console :

```
MATCH r=(n:Departements WHERE n.nom_departement =~ '(?i).*ca.*' ) return r
```

which return all departement where name contains 'ca' case insensitive

I try to code the same in Python like this :

```
query1 = "MATCH r=(n:Departements WHERE n.nom_departement =~ '(?i).*$filter.*' ) return r"
```

where filter = 'ca' (for exemple) and command :

```
records, summary, keys = driver.execute_query(query1, filter=str.upper())
```

the query return 0 records

Can you explain why ? Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a Cypher parameter inside a string. When it's surrounded by quotation marks, Cypher sees the $ as a character, not the start of a parameter name.

You can concatenate strings, including a string-valued parameter, to get the result you are looking for.

```
query1 = "MATCH r=(n:Departements WHERE n.nom_departement =~ '(?i).*' + $filter + '.*' ) return r"
```

Comment: Thank U Nathan
I fix my problem with your answer, and finally format query inside loop like this :
Before loop declare query string like this :    

`query1 = "MATCH r=(n:Departements WHERE n.nom_departement =~ '(?i).*{0}.*' ) return r"`
inside loop format query like this :  

` query1 = query1.format(str.upper())` 
Where str is a string entered by user

Thank you very much for your explain

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way of doing search instead of regex. It is using the keyword:  CONTAINS.  It is also case insensitive since both param and attribute (nom_dept) are converted into upper case.

```
import py2neo as pn
graph = pn.Graph("bolt://localhost:7687/", user="neo4j", password="awesome")
theCypherQuery= '''MATCH (n:Departements) 
WHERE toUpper(n.nom_departement) contains $filter
return n'''

def getNode(thisCypherQuery, parameter):
    cypherResult = graph.evaluate(thisCypherQuery, parameters = {'filter':parameter})
    return cypherResult

parameter = "ca"
someNode = getNode(theCypherQuery, parameter=parameter.upper())
print(someNode)
```

Comment: My alternative is to use this query instead of regex :  
`query2 = "MATCH r=(n:Departements WHERE apoc.text.toUpperCase(n.nom_departement) contains $filter ) return r"`  
Which work fine ! 